# dissappearing slash("/") when create an form dynammically

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

I'm trying to create some input forms in PHP dynamically. 
It's a function which returns the html into the view. (ZF2)

In php I've got this: `<input name="bla" type="text" value="bla" />`

Its becoming this: `<input name="bla" type="text" value="bla" >`

So the slash at the end is missing. can someone tell me why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are looking at source code on browser, it is normal. Relax

Comment: How are you viewing the HTML? Are you using developer tools right-click > "Inspect Element" or right-click > "view source"? Viewing the DOM in Developer Tools will hide the "/>", but they should be there in view source. If not, what function are you using to produce the view?

Comment: that's right. the source code is correct. thanks. but i need to find the stylebreaking part somewhere else...

Comment: not to mention that `<input>` is as  valid as `<input />` when it comes to HTML5

Answer (score 0):

The `input` element is a void element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input There are two ways to write a void element:

`<element>` or `<element />` (but never `<element></element>`) I don't really know the zend framework, but I guess it defaults to the first, which is the more standard way or writing things. See also question [Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)